# I get 401 (Unauthorized) and Invalid HTTP status code 401 for the POST/OPTIONS call. Works on POSTMAN/RESTCLIENT

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm new to Jquery and JqueryMobile . I'm having a bit of a trouble and was hoping someone here would help me. From what I understand, before I can actually do "POST", the browser does a "preflight" OPTIONS call. The problem with me is that the OPTIONS call fails with 401. I tested the api with RESTclient and POSTMAN and it works for just "POST".

I have one more block of code which is similar and makes a call to get the authorization token(authtoken). The only difference between this block and the other block are

1) Data block.

2) BeforeSend block.

The code for making the call.

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://myurl/api/APIName",
        beforeSend: function (request)
        {
            request.setRequestHeader('AuthToken', "This is where I'll insert my authtoken");
            request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "application/json");
            $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
        },
        complete: function () {
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
        },
        data: {FirstName: "Albert", LastName: "Einstein"},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
             alert(response.APIStatus.ErrorCode);

        },
        error: function () {
            alert(response.APIStatus.ErrorCode;
        }
    });
```

The code to get Authorization Token. This block does its work without any issue.

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://myurl/api/THEURLTOAUTHENTICAREME",
        beforeSend: function () {

            $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
        },
        complete: function () {
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
        },
        data: {username: "Nickolas", Password: "Te$l@"},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.AuthToken) {
                alert(response.AuthToken); 
            }else {
                alert(response.APIStatus.Message);
            }

        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Woops");
        }
    });
```

I'm not the one whose working on the api piece of the application, but I do know the person who are working on it. 
The first block needs to have an "authtoken" in the header and that's the reason why I'm doing  request.setRequestHeader('AuthToken', "This is where I'll insert my authtoken");. Am I doing this wrong?

Hitting the API in Postman: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYa8o.png

Console/Inspector from Chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFPfp.png

Please help me!